# Android SQLiteDatabase Insert Data to Column?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to this Android,  I want to know how to insert data into column? , like messaging app , when you click contact/people , it will display your data from that people , and that data cant be displayed to other,can u guys give me some link or keywords to search,sorry for my bad English., Thanks in Advance.

This is my Code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "WorkToDo.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "DATA_TABLE";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "Title";
    private static final String COLUMN_WORK = "Work";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 4);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_WORK + " TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public long insertTitle(String title) {
        long result;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TITLE, title);
        result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return result;
    }
    public ArrayList<Title> getTitles(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_TITLE,COLUMN_WORK};
        ArrayList<Title> titleArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TITLE));
            Title newTitle= new Title(title);
            newTitle.setTitle(title);
            titleArrayList.add(newTitle);
        }
        return titleArrayList;
    }
    public long insertWork(String work) {
        long result;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_WORK,work);
        result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return result;
    }

    public ArrayList<WorkOut> getWorks(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_TITLE,COLUMN_WORK};
        ArrayList<WorkOut> arrayList = new ArrayList<WorkOut>();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String work = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_WORK));
            WorkOut workOut = new WorkOut(work);
            workOut.setWork(work);
            arrayList.add(workOut);
        }
        return arrayList;
    }

}
```

...
I want to insert data of work into COLUMN_TITLE like this. and please tell me if something wrong with my code, and I know there's something wrong :) .

```
TABLE1(TITLE)      TABLE2(WORK)

title1             (work1,work2,work3....)


title2             (work4, work5,work6....)


title3             (work7, work8, work9...)
```

Comment: it's better to search first.

Comment: Check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW5JdoFT0Rlt3ry5Mjp7s8cT). Might be useful. I learned SQLite from here when I was beginner.

Comment: Do you already have a database setup?